# 404 angularjs http post to a php file

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I have hosted a little web app on heroku. My issue is when I try to execute a php file from angularjs, the console log says me that can't found it. On my localhost works perfectly!
Here is the code.

From the controller (app.js):

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'generarPDF.php',
            data: misProductos,
        }).
        then(function(response){
            alert(response.data);
        })
```

My php just receive the data and send it by mail. The controller file and the php file are in the same directory. 
The node server:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_3/index.html'));
});
app.get('/page_general_portfolio_3.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_3/page_general_portfolio_3.html'));
});
app.get('/page_general_about.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_3/page_general_about.html'));
});
app.get('/form_controls_md.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_3/form_controls_md.html'));
});
app.get('/ecommerce_products_edit.html', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/admin_3/ecommerce_products_edit.html'));
});
```

This is the heroku log:

> 2018-01-31T00:00:41.789571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes
>   with SIGTERM 2018-01-31T00:00:41.867855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process
>   exited with status 143 2018-01-31T00:00:51.631278+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `npm start`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `the console log says me that can't found it` api can' found or file can't found?

Answer (score 0):

What port are you using? you need to use

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT | 1234, ()=> console.log());
```

**process.env.PORT** don't forget this

Comment: Yes I'm listening at const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;